# Why is Dynamics CRM 2015 SDK RetrieveEntityRequest is not returning IsLogical in AttributeMetadata?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Given the following simple CRM SDK code:

```
using (var os = new OrganizationService(CrmConnection.Parse(".... some crm connection ..... "))
{
    var reReq = new RetrieveEntityRequest();
    reReq.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All;
    reReq.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;
    reReq.LogicalName = "opportunity";

    var reRes = os.Execute<RetrieveEntityResponse>(reReq);

    // null in my case?
    Console.WriteLine("AccountId: IsLogical = {0}", reRes.EntityMetadata.Attributes[0].IsLogical.Value) 

}
```

Why does IsLogical of the **AccountId** attribute (infact all attributes) not include a value (e.g is always null)

[image]

My understanding here it should be True for AccountId as this is a logical attribute.

**More info**  Im using the 2015 SDK Libraries from NUGET, and I am connecting to a 2013 instance of CRM.  Could this be the incompatibility, Am I using the right libraries?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the `IsLogical` attribute, as documented in the SDK, is for use in determining the sort-ability of a calculated field.

Per the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata.islogical.aspx) (link from BlueSam's answer):

> When you use logical attributes as sources for a calculated field the
>   values in the calculated field cannot be sorted.

If you are targeting a 2013 instance the value will be null. 2013 did not have calculated fields so it did not have a need for the `IsLogical` attribute.

If you are targeting a 2015 instance and looking at the `IsLogical` property for `accountid` the value will be *true* because `accountid` on the `opportunity` entity is a foreign key reference to the `account` entity.

The rule for calculated field is if the calculated field uses any field where `IsLogical == true` then the calculated field cannot be used for sorting.

It does **NOT** mean that the field is not editable on the UI, although it is true that many logical fields will not by editable on the UI it is not a rule per the SDK.

I modified your code to show IsLogical for all fields on the entity:

```
var reReq = new RetrieveEntityRequest();
reReq.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All;
reReq.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;
reReq.LogicalName = "opportunity";

var reRes = (RetrieveEntityResponse)conn.Execute(reReq);

foreach (var att in reRes.EntityMetadata.Attributes.OrderBy (a => a.LogicalName))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} IsLogical={1}",att.LogicalName, att.IsLogical.Value);
}
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks to this post, I now understand the reason as to *why* they added IsLogical to the SDK for 2015.  There is a definite relationship between the field appearing in the Attributes list and the IsLogical flag of an attribute being true.  AccountId in this instance is not on the relationships editor, nor the attribute editor.  It is fair to say I can not use IsLogical to identify the fields that should not be visible reliably, therefore I just need to control this with configuration.  FYI AccountId is calculated in the Opportunity view based on contact type.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this doesn't apply to most attributes in the system. See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata.islogical.aspx). Here's an excerpt:

> Logical attributes contain values which are stored in different
>   database tables than other attributes in the entity. In most cases
>   this internal implementation is not relevant to working with Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM.

Comment: If you query the attribute tables directly IsLogical is true for AccountID.  From my analysis it seems it uses this property to filter them anywhere the  meta data is displayed, e.g entity attributes, field lists etc.. e.g you can not see the accountId attribute on the opportunity entity solution UI.  So, it seems it *should* be set for some attributes (including the mentioned accountId)

Comment: Interesting. My understanding is that the attribute is logical if there is any data pulled in from outer entities/optionsets (e.g. Lookup Name, OptionSet Name)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IsLogical in the SDK has been introduced in 2015, and I'm using 2013 so its coming through as *Null*

They are still considered logical attributes in 2011/13 but they do not come back in the SDK.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you care.  What are you using the information for?

Comment: Specifically filter out attributes that should not be editable. E.g They would not naturally appear in the solution manager attributes UI.  Fix at the moment is to retain this information in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering attributes to keep out those which should not be edited, you should also look at the IsValidForUpdate property. This will tell you if the attribute is editable.

There are also attributes with AttributeType (or AttributeTypeName.Value) of 'Virtual' - these are never used so you can ignore them.